# Adding new Spark workers on AWS EC2 - access error

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have the existing oeprating Spark cluster that was launched with `spark-ec2` script. I'm trying to add new slave by following the instructions:

- Stop the cluster
- On AWS console "launch more like this" on one of the slaves
- Start the cluster

Although the new instance is added to the same security group and I can successfully SSH to it with the same private key, `spark-ec2 ... start` call  can't access this machine for some reason:

> Running setup-slave on all cluster nodes to mount filesystems, etc...
>
> [1] 00:59:59 [FAILURE] xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
>
> Exited with error code 255 Stderr: Permission denied (publickey).

, obviously, followed by tons of other errors while trying to deploy Spark stuff on this instance.

The reason is that Spark Master machine doesn't have an `rsync` access for this new slave, but the 22 port is open...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that SSH key generated on Spark Master was not transferred to this new slave. Spark-ec2 script with `start` command omits this step. The solution is to use `launch` command with `--resume` options. Then the SSH key is transferred to the new slave and everything goes smooth.

Yet another solution is to add the master's public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to the newly added slaves ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. (Got this advice on Spark mailing list)