# "Permission denied (publickey)" when starting AWS EC2 Spark multi node cluster from master

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, apache-spark, ssh, permission-denied

I have following this [guide](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/spinning-up-a-spark-cluster-on-spot-instances-step-by-step-e8ed14ebb3b) to create a multi node Spark cluster on AWS using EC2 instances. Everything has gone perfectly fine without error until I try to start the cluster from the master EC2 instance with:

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh
```

where i get a "Permission denied (publickey)" as follows:

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /usr/local/spark/logs/spark-ubuntu-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-ip-172-31-2-17.out
    ec2-34-205-81-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-34-205-81-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com,172.31.6.154' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
    ec2-34-205-255-52.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-34-205-255-52.compute-1.amazonaws.com,172.31.11.106' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
    ec2-34-201-21-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-34-201-21-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com,172.31.4.124' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
    ec2-34-205-81-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
    ec2-34-205-255-52.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
    ec2-34-201-21-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

The log file is as follows:

```
Spark Command: /usr/bin/java -cp /usr/local/spark/conf/:/usr/local/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master 
--host ip-172-31-2-17.ec2.internal --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
18/01/15 22:31:57 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 5772@ip-172-31-2-17
18/01/15 22:31:57 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
18/01/15 22:31:57 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
18/01/15 22:31:57 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
18/01/15 22:31:58 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... 
using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/01/15 22:31:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu
18/01/15 22:31:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu
18/01/15 22:31:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
18/01/15 22:31:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
18/01/15 22:31:58 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  
with view permissions: Set(ubuntu); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: 
Set(ubuntu); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/01/15 22:31:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
18/01/15 22:31:59 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://ip-172-31-2-17.ec2.internal:7077
18/01/15 22:31:59 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.0.2
18/01/15 22:31:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
18/01/15 22:31:59 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://ec2-34-205-4-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
18/01/15 22:31:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.
18/01/15 22:31:59 INFO StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
18/01/15 22:31:59 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
```

I have searched online for what this error is and a suggested solution was running the following on my master:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

No luck there either, it gave me this:

```
cat: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

Also, at the end of the guide someone suggested this:

> If you are having “permission denied” problems while starting up the
>   cluster, it’s possible you don’t have the private ssh key on the
>   master node. Once you move the private key to the master node, you’ll
>   also have to designate the private key as the default by specifying
>   the key location in .ssh/config. For example:
>
> ```
> IdentityFile ~/.ssh/spark_cluster.pem
> ```

But there is no part of the tutorial which talks of putting or moving ssh keys and I have no idea where to go from here now. I don't think I missed any instruction from the tutorial. All my machines are Ubuntu 16.04. Please help

Comment: What guide did you follow?

Comment: @Shaido I've edited the post to include the link . Thanks, I had forgotten it.

Comment: did you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with the SSH. A previous, similar, [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633365/adding-new-spark-workers-on-aws-ec2-access-error) got solved by copying the public key on the master node to a new slave node. In your case, try to generate a key (since it doesn't seem to exist) and then copy it to all the slave nodes.

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote_username@host:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```